# Images won't load in IE11

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net

At this moment i am designing a website in visual studio 2010, it will be an aspx-site with a mix of html, vb and css (i don't know how the offical language for this is called, so an explanation it will be). I am trying to build the website so that it will run in multiple environments. The two most important browsers are IE11 and Chrome (Though i try to make the site work good in Edge and Firefox).

Let's get to the problem:
When loading the webpage it behaves correctly; the menu is hidden and i need to select from a list. After i click on one of those items the selection-box dissapears and a dashboard and menu appear. But in IE11 the bar appears and invisible buttons apear; There is a small invisible box that is clickable and responds accordingly.

The code in the MasterPage.master responsible for the images looks as follows:

```
<div class="Menu">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDashboard" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonZones" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonGraphs" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonAnalysis" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonSimulation" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonDownload" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonHelp" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The code in the MasterPage.master.vb that handles the click looks as follows (changes accordingly to the Button, not needed to paste them all because they are similair):

```
If Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.ToLower = "~/dashboard.aspx" Then
    ImageButtonDashboard.ImageUrl = "\Pictures\Dashboard_active.png"
Else
    ImageButtonDashboard.ImageUrl = "\Pictures\Dashboard.png"
End If
```

And for the CSS i have the following part:

```
.Menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: right;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

The weird part is that it works in Edge, Firefox and Chrome. I have tried to change the z-index for the menu and even try to hide all bars that are at the place of the menu; no difference.

I tried to look back in earlier version because in my memory that is where it worked, apparantly id didn't work there either. I did this because i thought that some added code would influence this (the property visible). But all those changes don't have any influence.

When inspecting the element in IE11 and Edge, the code looks exactly the same for the menu, except that for the CSS part the images has different dimensions, but that is all.

I don't even have a clue where to start digging now (Google and Stack Overflow didn't gave me much help :() or what to try. Hope i have added all the information in a clearly manner :)

Regards,
Sander

Edit:
Added the heading of my code below, maybe it could be of any use.

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="CSS/StyleMain.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="CSS/StyleData.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Comment: The final release of IE was in 2013.  Microsoft has added nothing to it since then, and has no plans to do so.  They really don't want anyone to use it anymore.  It's obsolete.  Only a small percentage of people still use it, and have to put up with many things that don't work for them from many web sites other than yours.  Why worry about it?

Comment: did you checked with compatibility setting in IE11 try html tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">

Comment: @RayButterworth : Seeing as there are more people using IE than Edge, why shouldn't he? Maybe he's even already aware that a significant portion of his user base may, or will, use IE?

Comment: @Sander : Have you checked the resulting HTML code for your buttons?

Comment: @RayButterworth, It is needed because the website will only run on domains with no internet acces and it will likely run on windows server 2010, so no other browser are available.

Comment: @Yogesh, the tag did not change anything. I added the heading of my code to the post, maybe that will help something.

Comment: @VisualVincent, When inspecting the element (thus viewing the HTML-code) in Edge and IE11 the HTML is exactly the same:  <input name="ctl00$ImageButtonAnalysis" id="ImageButtonAnalysis" type="image" src="\Pictures\Analysis.png">

Comment: Is the `Pictures` directory part of your server's root directory? Try changing the backslashes to forward slashes: `/Pictures/Analysis.png`.

Comment: @VisualVincent, well, that did it, thank you a lot! :).. for a fast fix i changed /Pictures/Analysis.png to \Pictures/Analysis.png (made the folder into a variable). So only changing the first backslash to a forward slash did it... Can you elaborate on why this works? (changing all the backslashes to forward slashes) I know there is a difference and depending on the program you use a different one; file sharing on the network with backslash and browsing the internet with forward slash.

Comment: Don't know if i can ask it here:
The menu can be changed with the property Visible from the VB.net part (MenuGedr.Visible = True (or False)) Now this part doesn't seem to work, or in another spot the image is not clickable anymore, Though it is a link with <asp:ImageButton...>

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about ASP.NET to answer your new problem. However, as for the slashes: `/Pictures` means _"the `Pictures` directory in the **root of the website**"_. Likely, the other browsers interpret `\Pictures` as this as well in order to have broader compatibility, but IE doesn't. For the best compatibility should use forward slashes **only** for everything on the front-end, though.